# Is there a way to use different plugins for different browsers? (pdf browser plugin issues)

Tags: mac, browser, osx-lion

(My problem is actually a little more specific than "is there a way to use different plugins for different browsers" so there might be other solutions)

I'd like to find a way to view pdfs within my browsers using the best plugins for the respective browsers. I have tried various solutions, but nothing works for all browsers

- Chrome uses its own pdf plugin and ignore the things I installed in the Internet Plug-Ins folder. It works fine so I don't have an issue with it.
- the built-in Safari plugin works great, and I'd like to keep using it, but I need to figure out something for Firefox, which I also use frequently
- the [schubert|it](http://www.schubert-it.com/pluginpdf) plugin works but does not allow searching inside the pdf (the built-in Safari plugin let you do that)
- I dislike the [PDF Viewer by Mozilla Lab](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/pdfjs/) because it's very slow on my machine, plus it only loads the pages as you scroll down; it gets very annoying after a few pages
- the Adobe Reader plugin hasn't worked in Firefox in a long time. I'd get an error message saying "Adobe Reader cannot show documents in this browser". It [looks like](http://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/use-adobe-reader-plugin-view-or-download-pdf-files) the Adobe Reader doesn't work with Firefox on OS X.

Ideally I'd like to use the OS X built-in pdf viewer within Safari, and schubert|it in Firefox in Firefox (if possible, but if not, I'd stick with the PDF Viewer by Mozilla Lab). Is there a way to use different plugins for different browsers? (Or, are there other solutions?) Thanks!

I am on Mac OS X 10.7.5, Safari 6.0.2, Firefox 17.0.1.

Comment: You always use different plugins for different browsers. What do you mean?

Comment: for example, schubert|it plugin gets installed at /Library/Internet Plug-Ins/ and both Safari and Firefox would check this directory for plugins at launch. Therefore you cannot install it only for Firefox but not Safari.

Comment: Ah, I see, but there should be a browser-specific `plugins` sub-directory in the settings dir of each browser. Don't have access to a Mac to check right now, I'll post when I can get my hands on one.